# Accessing text data in web-hosted GIS Map (ESRI) via python

Tags: python, gis, esri

I would like to interact with a web-hosted GIS map application [here](https://dwrapps.utah.gov/fishing/fStart) to scrape data contained therein. The data is behind a toggle button.

Normally, creating a soup of the websites text via `BeautifulSoup` and `requests.get()` suffices to where the text data is parse-able, however this method returns some sort of esri script, and none of the desired html or text data.

Snapshot of the website with desired element inspected:
[image]

Snapshot of the button toggled, showing the text data I'd like to scrape:
[image]

The code's first mis(steps):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

site = 'https://dwrapps.utah.gov/fishing/fStart'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(site).text.lower(), 'html.parser')
```

The return of said soup is too lengthy to post here, but there is no way to access the html data behind the toggle shown above.

I assume use of `selenium` would do the trick, but was curious if there was an easier method of interacting directly with the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the site is get json from https://dwrapps.utah.gov/fishing/GetRegionReports (in the js function `getForecastData`)

so you can use it in requests:

```py
from json import dump
from typing import List
import requests
url = "https://dwrapps.utah.gov/fishing/GetRegionReports"
json:List[dict] = requests.get(url).json()

with open("gis-output.json","w") as io:
    dump(json,io,ensure_ascii=False,indent=4) # export full json from to the filename gis-output.json

for dt in json:
    reportData = dt.get("reportData",'') # the full text 
    displayName = dt.get("displayName",'')
    # do somthing with the data.
    """
    you can acsses also this fields:
    regionAdm = dt.get("regionAdm",'')
    updateDate = dt.get("updateDate",'')
    dwrRating = dt.get("dwrRating",'')
    ageDays = dt.get("ageDays",'')
    publicCount = dt.get("publicCount",'')
    finalRating = dt.get("finalRating",'')
    lat = dt.get("lat",'')
    lng = dt.get("lng",'')
    """
```

Comment: Where did you find that url for the json data? I couldn't nor can I now, find it in the source code.

Comment: there is `$("#changeForecastToggle").on('click', toggleForecast);` that points to `toggleForecast` -> `displayForecast(gl.reportArray)`=> use of `gl.reportArray` .

`gl.reportArray` get update on `getForecastData` that use `$.getJSON("GetRegionReports")`